# Jquery Mobile - $(document).ready(function() {});

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am new to jquery mobile.

I need help understanding the equivalent of document.ready() for jquery mobile.

I have 2 jsp pages as follow:

page1.jsp

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#page1', function(event){
    alert("page 1");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
  <header data-role="header">
  </header>
  <article data-role="content">
    page 1
  </article>
  <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <nav data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="page2.jsp>" data-icon="arrow-r">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

page2.jsp

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#page2', function(event){
    alert("page 2");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
  <header data-role="header">
  </header>
  <article data-role="content">
    page 2
  </article>
  <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <nav data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="page1.jsp>" data-icon="arrow-l">Page 1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

So when I initially load page 1, I will get an alert "page 1". But when I navigate to page 2, I do not get the alert "page 2"

But on page 2, I navigate back to page 1, I get an alert "page 1"

So why don't I get "page 2" alert when I load page 2 via navigation?

I am trying to learn jquery mobile so please an explanation and any code example would help to me understand it a lot.

I tried to read through jquery mobile documentation but not understanding it.

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you loading jQuery on these pages?

Comment: I load them in <head> section of the jsp page

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: If you have solved your problem then you should post your solution here - it's OK to answer your own question. There's nothing more frustrating than coming to the site and seeing that someone has solved the same problem, but not finding the answer

Comment: I solved it by combining all the js script into a single js file and load it one first page.

Answer (score 0):

Your script isn't running because it technically isn't being loaded.  jQuery Mobile follows links by intercepting their normal functionality (which is to navigate to a new page) and instead loads the page's content via an AJAX request.  If successful, it then takes the [data-role=page] element and adds it to your existing page.  The result is that the new page is loaded, but you never **really** leave the page that you started from.

Anything not within a [data-type=page] element is not loaded during this, including your scripts.  You can fix this by by moving your `<script>` tag inside of page2's [data-role=page] element.  If you do this, keep in mind that any code loaded this will will remain as other pages are loaded, and you might have things start interacting in ways you never intended.

Another option is to simply force jQuery Mobile to actually navigate to new pages when links are clicked.  Check out [their documentation](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/pages/page-links.html) for how to do that.